# Unable to understand ObjectMapper writeValueAsString(Object value) method behavior

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I am using `ObjectMapper` to get value as `String` from `JsonNode` but see this weird behavior. I am missing something here. Can someone explain why is the Actual result has `double quotes` in it?
I expect this test to pass but the assertion fails:

**Unit Test:**

```
@Test
public void testGetValueAsString() throws JsonProcessingException {
  ObjectMapper fasterXmlMapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
  JsonNode node = new TextNode("{}");
  String valueAsString = fasterXmlMapper.writeValueAsString(node);
  assertEquals("{}", valueAsString);
}
```

**Test Run Output:**

```
expected:<[{}]> but was:<["{}"]>
Expected :{}
Actual   :"{}"
```

**Here I am referring to following library and classes:**

I am using `jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar`

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode` and 
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation a `TextNode` is

> /**
>   * Value node that contains a text value.
>   */

So `TextNode` wraps its argument in `""`. In order to make your test running you either need to chose a different subclass of `Node` or adjust the assertion to `assertEquals("\"{}\"", valueAsString);`.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, but even when I do `assertEquals(node.asText(), valueAsString);` it fails.

Comment: When calling `node.asText()` then you will get the internal value of the `TextNode` which is a String of `{}`. When calling `writeValueAsString(textNode)` then the internal value is wrapped in `"` and the output is the string `"{}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read on [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) that `string` is:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, **wrapped in**
>   **double quotes**, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as
>   a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java
>   string.

And this is what `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode` does, wraps `{}` in double quotes which gives `"{}"`.

If you want to have an empty `JSON Object` you can create `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode` instance:

```
JsonNode node = mapper.getNodeFactory().objectNode();
```